# What is this dynamics question asking me to do?

Tags: classical-mechanics

I've made it to the the final part of this question and got the expression with arctan in it:
[image]

However, I'm not sure what the final part is asking me to do.  I know I've got to plug the new values into the right places, but I'm not sure what the end goal is. After putting in all the values $t_{\text{max}}$ and $U$ are both left and I don't know what to do, due to me not being able to do $\arctan(t)$ or $\tan(u)$ or anything. Anyway, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think the question is asking you what the limit of this expression is as $u$ goes to infinity.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input.  I've seen that as u tends to infinity arctan tends to pi/2.  I don't know how to formally show this though, because i just put increasingly large numbers into my calculator to i stayed at that figure.  Substituting pi/2 for arctan(root((k/g)u)), I ended up with t is equal to or less than pi/(2root(gk))=0.7096 to 4 dp.  Does that make sense at all?